# Call of default constructor with unexpected results

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I encountered unexpected behavior of default constructor. Having this class

```
class Data {
public:
    Data() { std::cout << "default ctor"; }
};
```

and calling

```
Data(x);
```

calls the default constructor, whereas calling

```
double x;
Data(x);
```

produces *conflicting declaration 'Data x'*.

I suppose it is some kind of vexing parse, but I don't see the logic behind that. Can you please explain how the g++ compiler sees that?

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like it seeing it as `Data x;`, a declaration of a new local variable named `x` of type `Data`.  Is that what all that you are looking to know or is there more?

Comment: In the first example you’re creating a data variable named x.

Comment: To the downvoter: I really don't know how to put the question better if you encounter some strange behavior and don't even know what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here comes from way back when C was introduced.  When you write

```
type(name);
```

it is parsed as declaring a variable like

```
type name;
```

That means in

```
Data(x);
```

you declare a variable named `x` that is of type `Data` and in

```
double x;
Data(x);
```

you declare a variable name `x` with the type `double` and then try to declare a variable named `x` with the type `Data`.  You can't redefine a variable like that so you get an error.

---

If you want to just declare a temporary `Data` then the syntax would be

```
Data();
```

Comment: To make this make sense so that you'll remember it as something rational and not some weird rule, start by imagining if you did `Data (*x)[10];`. What error would you expect? Now think through `Data (*x);`. What would make sense there? Then you're ready to think about `Data (x);` and lastly `Data(x);`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Isn't `Data (*x)[10];` legal?  `x` should be a pointer to an array of ten `Data`.

Comment: Yes, precisely. And so `Data (*x);` is legal too. And so is `Data (x);`. Hence, in all these cases, you'll get precisely the error the OP got because they're all legal.